# How to store id in database but to show name in modelchoicefield in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

Here is my code in forms.py

```
manager_idd=forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Manager",widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class":"form- 
control"}),queryset=Manager.objects.all().values_list('id','name',named=True)
```

I am trying to show names in choice field but want to get id of selected name, as this is a foreign key in database. I want to save it as an id in database but to show as name in choice field. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
manager_idd=forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Manager",widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class":"form- 
control"}), queryset=Manager.objects.all().values_list('id','name',named=True))
```

Define the `__str__()` method to return `self.name` in your `Manager`, so it will be used as representation in select options.

```
class Manager(models.Model):
    ....
    def __str__(self):
       return self.name

# would yield
<select id="id_field1" name="field1">
<option value="obj1.pk">obj.name</option>
<option value="obj2.pk">obj.name</option>
...
</select>
```

> The `__str__()` method of the model will be called to generate string
> representations of the objects for use in the field’s choices [[Doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).

Comment: so,,i have to define this function in model.py and to remove values_list() things in froms.py? Or further declaration is to be done ? like self.name will be used anywhere or just define str(self) in models.py

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to explicitly extract `name` out, if you primary_key is not id, you can set using `to_field_name="id"` and it will make the value as `obj1.id`..., read carefully of the documentation, it is well written here

Comment: @None `.__str__()` is used in many places, if you don't specify this method, you will find your admin with `Manager object(1)` in other foreignkeys, list display, etc..

Comment: yes for that i used values_list() but found another issue here that in database, it is also saving name instead of id. Thank your for  your help. It is resolved.